# Rectangle line and Dash Line

Tags: java, android, paint

If I draw with Rectangle line and after that I want to draw with dash line my rectangle line will be transformed in dash line. I use this code:

This is MyLine.java

```
public class MyLine { //  line
public float x,y;
public float xStart,yStart,xEnd,yEnd;

public Paint paint = new Paint();
Path path = new Path();

public MyLine()
{

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{20,30}, 0));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    path = new Path();
}

public void mouseDown(Path path,float xDown,float yDown){
    path.moveTo(xDown, yDown);
    path.lineTo(xDown, yDown);

    xStart = xDown;
    yStart = yDown;
}

public void mouseUp(Path path,float xUp,float yUp){
    path.lineTo(xUp, yUp);
    xEnd = xUp;
    yEnd = yUp;
}

public void draw(Canvas c){
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10,20}, 0));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    path = new Path();

    c.drawLine(xStart,yStart,xEnd,yEnd,paint);
}

public void changeColor(int color){
    paint = new Paint(paint);
    paint.setColor(color);
    //myPaint.setColor(color);
}

}
```

Here is some code from CanvasView.java where I think is problem.

```
public void setDashLine(){

    dashedLine = true;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    myCanvas = new Canvas();
    path = new Path();
}

public void setNormalLine(){
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(null);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    myCanvas = new Canvas();
    path = new Path();
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setPathEffect(null);
if(bitmap!=null){

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
     for(MyCircle circle:circleList){// draw circles

         myCanvas.drawCircle(getCircleMidPointX(circle.firstX, circle.lastX),getCircleMidPointY(circle.firstY, circle.lastY),circle.radius,myPaint);
     }

}
for(MyLine line:lineList){ //draw lines
     if(dashedLine)
         line.paint.setPathEffect(dashEffect);
     else
         line.paint.setPathEffect(null);
        canvas.drawLine(line.xStart, line.yStart, line.xEnd, line.yEnd, line.paint);
  }
final OnTouchListener drawLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              undonePaths.clear();
              path.reset();
              myLine = new MyLine();
              myLine.xStart = event.getX();
              myLine.yStart = event.getY();

            return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            myLine.xEnd = event.getX();
            myLine.yEnd = event.getY();

            invalidate();
            lineList.add(myLine);
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};

final OnTouchListener drawDashedLineListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        FirstActivity.ll.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

        switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              myLine = new MyLine();

             return true;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            invalidate();
            lineList.add(myLine); 
            break;

          default:
            Log.d("mock it up", "Unknown touch event  " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
};
```

If you can see something where is wrong please tell me how can make to be useful.

Comment: it is because you are using the same paint object.

Comment: you want to refer at MyLine?

Comment: use a boolean value. false means draw only normal line. true means draw only dashed line. try this onDraw()

Comment: you want to change return true to falls at drawLineListener?

Comment: while draw on ondraw() check boolean value if true dashed line then draw dashed line (do not draw the normal line). Set the boolean value according to what user chooses.

Comment: use a different paint for normal line and dashed line like paintnomral and paintdashed.

Comment: can you edit my code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27183/discussion-between-marius-hincu-and-raghunandan)